# How to return text values from Bootstrap Multi-Select and write SQL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a code in asp that generates the list of users I need, through a ViewBag.

the list loads normally, however, when selecting multiple values, only the first value (ID) is written to SQL.
in the html code, I noticed that only the first value is <option selected="selected"...>

I need all my data selected (selectpicker) or (select2), to be written in my SQL field and returned on the screen as "tags" for the case of (select2) or selected in (selectpicker).

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="SCusernominal" class="control-label"></label><br />
     <select asp-for="SCusernominal" asp-items="ViewBag.USER_FINAL" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple="multiple" id="SCusernominal" data-actions-box="true" data-size="5" data-width="100%"></select>
</div>
```

[image: PrintScreen Image SELECTPICKER on page]

Comment: Can you let us know what your database table looks like?

Answer (score 0):

First use  Selectpicker then insert a property in  your model to pass selected item to the controller to save in your database, like this:

```
  public List<int> SelectedGroup{get;set;}
```

and in your view :

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedGroup, this.ViewBag.Groups as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control"})

<script>
  $('#selectGroup').selectpicker(
                {
                    width: '100%',
                    title: '- [select more..] -',   
                    size: 6,
                   
                });


</script>
```